# c2664 cannot convert parameter 2 from 'std::string' to 'const void *'

Tags: c++, c++11

This is where I call the function..

```
memcpy(dataHashResult,sha1.operator()(dataBuffer,16),16);
```

I changed

/// compute SHA1 of a memory block

```
std::string operator()(const void* data, size_t numBytes);
```

to

```
std::string operator()(BYTE* data, size_t numBytes);
```

the types of buffers are..

```
unsigned char dataBuffer[64];

unsigned char dataHashResult[64];
```

Any help would be appreciated ..I'm new to C++.. 
Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: The `operator()` overload means that you can (should) use the `sha1` object like a function: `sha1(dataBuffer, 16)`.

Comment: Okay I didn't know how much to post exactly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
memcpy(dataHashResult,sha1.operator()(dataBuffer,16).c_str(),16);
```

The problem is that `memcpy` needs a pointer to copy from. Your original code gives it a `std::string` *object*. Luckily, `std::string` has a `c_str()` function that returns the "C-style" string, i.e. a `const char*`.

Comment: Thanks a lot its solved .. ! For the answer as well as prompt reply !!

Comment: yes I did... for 10mins it would not let me do it. .. Thanks for the explanation as well @Adam